# log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [eproc-file-out]

Tags: log4j

I am getting the error in my server.log file which is given below:

`2018-03-23 17:34:38,857 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8) log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [eproc-file-out].`

> My question is that can anyone explain regarding the **category tag** and can I use the same **appender-ref ref="eproc-file-out"** for all the category tags....???

My log4j.xml configuration file is given below:

```
<appender name="eproc-file-out" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/eProcurement/eProcurementServerLog.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'dd'.txt'"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="com.presentation">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="eproc-file-out"/>
</category>
<category name="com.service">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="eproc-file-out"/>
</category>
<category name="com.dao">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="eproc-file-out"/>
</category>
<category name="org.apache">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="eproc-file-out"/>
</category>
<category name="org.springframework">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="eproc-file-out"/>
</category>
<category name="com.metaparadigm">
    <priority value="ERROR"/>
    <appender-ref ref="eproc-file-out"/>
</category>
<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="eproc-file-out"/>
</root>
```

I did google as well as referred to StackOverflow for this error but I didn't found the solution for my question regarding category tag.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From log4j manual:

public class Category

This class has been deprecated and replaced by the Logger subclass. It will be kept around to preserve backward compatibility until mid 2003.

Logger is a subclass of Category, i.e. it extends Category. In other words, a logger is a category...

...

There is absolutely no need for new client code to use or refer to the Category class. Whenever possible, please avoid referring to it or using it.